# Luxury vinyl plank sealing

Tags: flooring, sealing, vinyl-flooring

Im installing glue-down shaw vinyl planks in my bathroom, and although they are themselves not porous, and should stand up to the traffic and water, i would like to seal them to enhance their durability. Mainly due to the seems..

I have looked around a bit, and everyone just says you shouldnt have to, and thats it. I may not HAVE to, but i would like to.

Any advice on brands or types of sealers? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally, for best results follow the manufacturer's instructions (and to retain valid warranty). Shaw does not recommend a seam sealer for their LVT/LVP products, only for their sheet vinyl flooring.

Comment: I did see they dont recommend. That keepa the warranty valid for my vinyl, but what of the wood beneath that will be destoyed if water gets through the seams?

Comment: If you butt them up tight to each other, and use a 100lb. roller (or hand roller in tight spots) as recommended, water is unlikely to get through under normal circumstances. If you leave water to stand or you experience a flood, all bets are off whether or not you use some kinda sealer. I occasionally use regular vinyl floor wax on the whole floor, assuming (right or wrong) that it gets down into the seams and gives added protection.